# Show progressbar when executing some SQL query

Tags: c#, .net

I want to show progress bar when my program executes some SQL Server query. I use code from [C# Tutorial - Progress Bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ae1_6ELGVYw)

The code below :

```
 private Task ProcessData(List<Tuple<int,string>> list, IProgress<ProgressReport> progress)
 {
        int index = 1;
        int totalprogress = list.Count;
        var progressreport = new ProgressReport();

        return Task.Run(()=> {
            for(int i = 0; i < totalprogress; i++)
            {
                Tuple<int, string> temp = list[i];
                int id = temp.Item1;
                string address = temp.Item2;
                label_autoupdate.Text = string.Format("Processing ...{0}",address);
                excuteAutoUpdate(id, address);
                progressreport.PercentComplete = i++ * 100 / totalprogress;
                progress.Report(progressreport);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
           // groupBox_autoupdate.Visible = false;

        });
}

private  async void button_update_tracking_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Tuple<int, string>> list = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
    //..
    var progress = new Progress<ProgressReport>();

    progress.ProgressChanged += (o, report) =>
        {
            progressBar1.Value = report.PercentComplete;
            progressBar1.Update();
        };

    await ProcessData(list, progress);
}
```

But this function doesn't work as I expected. My "list" have 13 items but it only execute about 7-8 items.I must click button "update" many times to get all things I need. I don't know how to force program wait the function "excuteAutoUpdate"(in this case) finish then continue loop function. I'm very new to n multi-threaded programming, so there are many things I do not understand. I search some thing like background worker but i can't apply it for my case.

Could you please show me how to solve it ?

Thanks you!

Comment: if you have exactly followed the video you mentioned, then your code has an error on line `progressreport.PercentComplete = i++ * 100 / totalprogress;`. In the video it is index++, you have written i++. You are incrementing the loop variable.

Comment: FYI your percent will always return zero for the first element because you use `i++*100` which will be `0*100` since `++` returns the previous value. You also increment twice (here and in the loops third term) change this line to `(i+1) *100/totalprogress` or remove the `i++` from the loop itself and change that line to `++i *100/totalprogress`  the fact you increment twice in your loop is why it only seems to run some of them, because in fact I gets incremented doubly and half are skipped

Comment: @ Amey Kamat ,@  pinkfloydx33 , Thank for comment. The problem doesn't  solve after change to (i+1).

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing `i` twice in each loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<totalprogress;i++) // HERE
{
    ...
    progressreport.PercentComplete = i++ * 100 / totalprogress; // AND HERE
    ...
}
```

So you are effectively only processing (at best) half of the results. This is why you must continually run it to actually process everything.

Also note, that since post-increment (`i++`) returns the value of `i` before the increment, your first loop would report Percent complete as 0

`i++*100/totalprogress` => `0*100/totalprogress` => `0`

Change your code to:

```
for(int i=0;i<totalprogress;i++) 
{
    ...
    progressreport.PercentComplete = (i+1) * 100 / totalprogress; // This line
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could also change it to:

```
for(int i=0;i<totalprogress;)  //remove i++
{
    ...
    progressreport.PercentComplete = (++i) * 100 / totalprogress; // change to pre-increment
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply ,After i change from  i++ to  (i+1)  the problem still occur.The function"excuteAutoUpdate" take 7-8 second to finish.